# The "CudaCompile" task was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cuda

I am trying to get started working with CUDA.

I fresh installed the trial version of VS2010 professional and downloaded the visual studio add on on NVIDIA's website ([here](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) )

I have a correct driver version installed, and the Nsight add on automatically installs the CUDA Toolkit.

Problem is, whatever CUDA project I try to compile, I always get this error :

```
1>  Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB3686: Unable to create Xaml task.  Compilation failed.  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB3686: Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\uq13nrom.0.cs' could not be found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB3686: No inputs specified
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB3686: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB4036: The "CudaCompile" task was not found
```

Even when using the solutions provided in CUDA samples
I never used Visual Studio before, and I could not find ANY resource on the web related to this error.

I spent the whole day trying to fix it. I also tried to uninstall/reinstall everything; no success.

What drives me crazy is that right after the install my projects actually did build for an hour or two. And for a reason I can't explain, everything started failing.

I'd be really, really glad for any information you could give me. I don't see any other way to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps a permissions problem? Can you try running visual studio as administrator? (right click on devenv.exe, select "run as administrator")

Comment: @talonmies Why remove the Thx in my message? I think it is important :s

Comment: @harrism. Thx for your comment. I did not try it, as my code was compiling this morning :)

Comment: @jlengrand: Extraneous greetings, thanks, signatures etc are discouraged in questions and answers. Stackoverflow has a sophisticated voting and acceptance system. Those are the ways to show appreciation for quality answers you receive.

Comment: @talonmies. I see the point. My thank you will come in the form of an upvote then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I woke up this morning and directly got in front of the computer, a coffee in the hand, already expecting to spend the whole day just trying to get my tools working

. . . till I realized everything was working fine.

**The very same code** that leads to the error at midnight compiles just perfectly this morning .

The only difference ? **Updates in Visual Studio**. 
Here is a screenshot of all the updates that have been applied during my sleep :

[image: Updates performed on VS2010]

I bet one of those guys solved my problem, **probably the .NET framework 4** related.

Hope this can help someone ;)

Comment: Or perhaps you just hadn't rebooted after installing everything the first time...

Comment: Oh I did man, and several times ;). I even tried to reboot between each tool I installed

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with configuration. There is something messed up [by me/you] in the project setting file. I am facing this problem while updating an old project from CUDA 4.4 to CUDA 5.5. I tried modifying the old project file according to one of the new project files... changing build target and other related things................

New project is compile and executing, whereas, the old updating project lead me to this page. I'll update the thread with a solution later. Definitely, it is not .NET framework or any updates in my case

EDIT: I copied the .prop and other files from CUDA installation directory to Visual Studio directory and it started working again. Perhaps, I modified these files incorrectly.